# Thymeleaf th:text incorrectly getting transformed to boolean from messages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to display a label where the contents are being sourced from a message source as the application supports multiple languages. My issue is that the message for English is 'Yes' or 'No' which gets transformed to true/false by thymeleaf. It looks something like this:

```
<label th:text="#{formMessage.confirm}">Yes</label>
```

Where: `formMessage.confirm=Yes` for English, but is transformed to true. This, of course, is happening for Spanish 'No' being transformed to false.

My question is how do I just force it to display 'Yes' instead of thymeleaf transforming it to a boolean? I am having a hard time tracking down documentation for this, though I am sure I can't be the first person to run into this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the message source, in your case? If I use a properties file (which I think is the [default approach](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#using-thtext-and-externalizing-text)), then "Yes" is rendered as "Yes" - as expected.

Comment: @andrewjames Thanks for commenting. I just figured out the issue and boy is my face red. I was loading the languages on startup to a custom MessageSource. The messages were in a yaml file format and I forgot to put quotes around the Yes/No messages which caused them to be transformed to boolean value.

Comment: No worries. Glad you solved it. It's my turn to be the [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer on my own and thought I would throw it up here even though it's unique to my situation.

I am loading the languages on startup to a custom MessageSource. The messages are in a yaml file format and I forgot to put quotes around the Yes/No messages which caused them to be transformed to boolean values.

In yaml `property: Yes` gets transformed to `true` and `property: "Yes"` is kept as a string.

Lesson learned.